# How to make an event for elements selection in DOM based on event.shiftKey?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I cannot understand how to make work `event.shiftKey` condition for elements selection from `previous` `target` element to the `current target`, that clicked after firstone... Other conditions are working perfect.

P.S. 
DO NOT click on any element by **shift+left_click**, because you will crash the page!

```js
 function clickOnLi(event) {

  var target = event.target;
  var li = menu.querySelectorAll('li');

  if (target.tagName != 'LI') return;

  if (event.ctrlKey) {
   if (target.className != 'greenLi') {
    target.classList.add('greenLi');
   } else if (target.className == 'greenLi') {
    target.classList.remove('greenLi');
   }    
  }

  if (event.shiftKey){
   target.className = 'greenLi';
 
   for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    do { 
     li[i].className == 'greenLi';
    } while (li[i] != target);
   }
  }

  if (!event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey) {

   target.className = 'greenLi';

   for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[i] != target) {

     li[i].className = '';
    }
   }
  }
 }

 menu.addEventListener( 'click', clickOnLi );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

 li {
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .greenLi {
  background-color: green;
 }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

 <ul id="menu">
  <li>Крис</li>
  <li>Робин</li>
  <li>Бэтмен</li>
  <li>Супермен</li>
  <li>Халк</li>
 </ul>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic inside `if (event.shiftKey)` block is incorrect. Replace your:

```
if (event.shiftKey){
    ...
}
```

to

```
if (event.shiftKey){
    target.className = 'greenLi';
    let alreadySelectedLiIndex = -1;
    let justSelectedLiIndex = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        if (li[i].className == 'greenLi' && li[i] != target)
            alreadySelectedLiIndex = i;
        if (li[i] == target)
            justSelectedLiIndex = i;

    }
    if (alreadySelectedLiIndex != -1){
        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            if (alreadySelectedLiIndex < i && i <= justSelectedLiIndex
               || justSelectedLiIndex <= i && i < alreadySelectedLiIndex){
               li[i].classList.add('greenLi');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just need to understand how you did it :)

Comment: In the first loop we find  the index of item that was selected before (`alreadySelectedLiIndex`) and index of target `li`. In the second loop we add the css class to `lis` that between already selected `li` and target `li` including the last one. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

the shiftKey event is correct, the issue is with your do-while loop. You have 3 states that you need to check... target, classname with greenLi, and lastly everything else that is neither of the previous two. 
Your IF block should look like the following:

```
    if (event.shiftKey){
        target.className = 'greenLi';

        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            if (li[i].className == 'greenLi') {
                //do nothing
            }else if(li[i] != target){
                li[i].className = '';
            }
        }
    }
```